# Neural Networks Weight matrices explained

Tags: python, neural-network

Hi guys was wondering if anyone could help me with what I would actually answer for this question on a upcoming exam I have on AI in Python. The question confuses me as I thought I would usually need more info to answer but it is not provided. the question asked is

> A Python class is used to represent a neural network and the feed forward operation is called as indicated below:
>
> ' y_hat = NN.forward(X) '
>
> where y_hat is the output and X is the input matrix.
>
> The neural network has an input size of 80, one hidden layer of size 40 and an output layer of size 1.
>
> What size will be the W1 and W2 matrices?

If anyone could help me with this as my lecturer is not replying to the classes emails.
Many Thanks!

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is a parameter count question, keep in mind there are also biases in the layers. There is no extra information needed I think, try to think of how the network would actually look like with the architecture described. Cordially, your lecturer Mr. Thompson. (Just kidding lol)

Comment: I think you have a typo: ' y_hat = NN.forward(X) '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feedforward Neural Network looks like this:

Input Layer(80x1) - W1(?x?) - Hidden(40x1) - W2(?x?) - Output(1x1)

- X is of size 80x1 and the Hidden Layer is of size 40, using the formula H=W1*X => W1 is of size 40x80
- The hidden layer is of size 40x1 and the output layer of size 1, using the formula Y=W2*H => W2 is of size 1x40

This will help:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedforward_neural_network

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate it! Last question its a part B but it asks
" Which network parameters will be used in back propogation? What are these derivatives used for?"
Any idea?

Comment: Which answer is correct as @Guillem has answerd w1=(80,40) w2=(40,1) which I at first thought, so why does it become (40,80) (1,40)? As you previously had it the first way but then changed it. Thank you in advance

Comment: The formula for the output of the hidden layer is: H = W1 * X that's a matrix notation formula => the number of columns of W1 must be equal to the number of rows of X and the number of Rows of W1 must be equal to the number of rows of the output H => W1 has size : 40 rows X 80 columns

Answer (score 3):

Let's say :

- X input vector, (size 80*1)
- H hidden layer vector, (size 40*1)
- Y output vector, (size 1*1)

You have :

- H = W1 * X
- Y = W2 * H

So :

- W1 has size (40*80)
- W2 has size (1*40)

Note : size (m*n) means m rows, n columns

Answer (score 1):

By your description I suppose that you have two layers, where the first layer outpits a tensor of batch x 40 and the second layer a batch x 1 tensor, meanwhile the input is a tensor of batch x 80.

Then the weights dimentions are:

W1: 80x40 -> first layer
W2: 40x1-> out layer